# what does "so as not to" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> IN THE GLOOM of a grey and freezing late-January morning it is a
> forbidding place. Its location is also secret, beyond the fact that it
> is somewhere in Kharkiv province in Ukraine’s north-east. Soldiers
> arriving or departing from what is the country’s only military
> rehabilitation centre dedicated to post-traumatic stress disorder
> (PTSD) **do so** in civvies, **so as not to draw attention**.

what is the meaning of "do so" in this paragraph? and does this have any relationship with the part "so as not to draw attention".
if you can offer some detailed explanation,I will be very delighted

Answer (score 2):

"Do so" is a phrase used to mean "perform the action under discussion". It is used to avoid repeating the same words. In this case, it refers back to the action "arriving and departing". The author could have written, "Soldiers arriving or departing ... arrive or depart in civvies ..." But that would have been a little redundant. So instead, in the second case he says "do so" rather than repeating the same words.

This is particularly commonly used when it takes many words to describe the action. Like, "She taught the dancers to stand on the toes of one foot and twirl around with their arms extended. The students were required to stand on the toes of one foot and twirl around with their arms extended gracefully and skillfully to pass the class." That's a lot of words to repeat and just sounds awkward, so a writer would likely instead say, "The students were required to do so gracefully and skillfully ..." etc.

There's no particular connection between "do so" and "so as not to draw attention", beyond both being in the same sentence and describing the same events.

"So as ..." means that what follows is the reason for something. Like, "I put on a heavy coat so as to keep warm."

"... not to ..." is a simple negation. The reason was to NOT do something, rather than to do something.

"... draw attention" means to appear or act in some way that is likely to cause people to notice. Like, the purpose of a giant billboard with spotlights pointing at it is to draw attention.

So in this case, the soldiers dressed in civilian clothes "so as not to draw attention". That is, the reason why they dressed in civilian clothes was to avoid causing people to notice. Presumably to notice that they were soldiers going in and out of a rehabilitation facility.

Comment: thank you,your explanation is articulated

Answer (score 1):

The *so* in *do so* refers to the action(s) described before that:

> arriving or departing from what is the country’s only military rehabilitation centre dedicated to post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD)

It could be read as "they do what they do in this way".

That *so*, referring back to "arriving or departing" does *not* refer forward to "so as not to draw attention".
"So as not to draw attention" refers to "arriving or departing in civilian clothing".

A simplified rewrite of the sentence could be

> Soldiers wear civilian clothes when they arrive at or depart from the center. The reason they wear civilian clothes is to avoid attention.

Comment: thank you,your answer is easy to understand and concise